# How do I integrate Google Website Optimizer into my Google Analytics account?

Tags: google-analytics, google-website-optimizer

I did everything asked of me in the following link:  http://support.google.com/websiteoptimizer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=77075

But am still not seeing my Google Optimizer stats inside Google Analytics.

Do both of my Account Ids have to be set differently or the same???

Answer (score 1):

[Using Google Analytics and Website Optimizer Simultaneously](http://support.google.com/websiteoptimizer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55906)

You must setup Google Analytics separately from Website Optimizer.